# Issue running apt-get commands

Tags: networking, apt

When ever I run apt-get update and upgrade I get various different error messages.

There are a lot of 503 Service Unavailable yet I can ping the IP addresses and get replies.
Also, gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.

Below are the errors I am getting at the end of apt-get update

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.concerto-signage.org/packages/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 173.232.104.112 80]
E: Failed to fetch https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
E: Failed to fetch https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, firewall, etc.?